# Change algorithm numbering in latex

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I have a code as follows. I do not know why I cannot change the numbering of pseudo-codes using the *algorithm* environment. Could you please help me with that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{\thesection.\arabic{algocf}}
\setcounter{algocf}{0}

\section{Appendix}

This algorithm \ref{alg1}.

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{The assignment procedure}\label{alg1}
\algsetup{\small}
\scriptsize
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Retrieve input parameters, including the intended room ($r$), the required qualification level ($q$), and the array of tasks required by room $r$ ($T$)
\State Propagate each element of array $T$ based on the number of SMs required for the relevant task
\State Detect qualified SMs for serving tasks of type $q$ (store in $C$)
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thealgocf}` is used with the `algorithm2e` package, which you don't load in your code. This is why your code results in an error message such as " Command \thealgocf undefined."

Comment: You probably wanted to use `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thesection.\arabic{algorithm}}` instead. Applying this change, the code still results in an error message regarding `\algsetup` being undefined. (This command appears to be used i combination with the `algorithmic` package, but with a different syntax). To change the font size of you algorithm, replace `\algsetup{\small}
\scriptsize` with `\small`. If you on the other hand just want to alter the font size of the line numbers, use `\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\small #1:}` instead.