# How to override the numbers in an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, line-numbering, algorithmicx

I have tried a few ways I found here, including [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311789/how-to-reinitialize-the-lines-counter-for-algorithms), and [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601852/change-algorithm-numbering-in-latex), there are more but I can't remember them.

The issue I'm having is I'd like "Fifth Instruction" to start on 5, I know "Third Instruction" has the correct number by accident, but none of my attempts seem to work. I'm happy with the indented sections being automatically renumbered, but even if it was one numbering the whole way down (1-13) but indented I'd be happy - I can't seem to manage that either.

Any help is really appreciated!

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State First Instruction
\State Second Instruction
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \State Instruction 2.1
     \State Instruction 2.2
\end{algorithmic}\\
Third Instruction\\
Fourth Instruction
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \State Instruction 4.1
     \State Instruction 4.2
     \State Instruction 4.3
\end{algorithmic}\\
Fifth Instruction
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \State Instruction 5.1
     \State Instruction 5.2
\end{algorithmic}\\
Instruction 6
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: How it currently looks]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should probably either load `algorithm` or `algorithm2e`.

Comment: Thanks, I have both loaded..

Comment: This, I see very clearly. But when I try to compile your example, I get errors from loading both packages. Therefore, I would suggest that you chose just one of both packages since they seem to get into conflict with each other.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that makes sense. I have left it with algpseudocode and algorithm, but I'm still getting the same issue. I've tried again with  \newcounter and \setcounter but it's still not changing them. Any ideas what else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess, nesting `algorithmic` environments is not the way to go here. Take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352056/47927) for a possible way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way with continuous numbering is to use extra indents with `\hspace`. To be consistent with the default indentation of `algorithmic` you can use `\algorithmicindent` as the value for the extra indent (this is `1.5em` by default).

MWE (note that I removed `algorithm2e` because it was causing an error):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State First Instruction
\State Second Instruction
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 2.1
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 2.2
\State Third Instruction
\State Fourth Instruction
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 4.1
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 4.2
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 4.3
\State Fifth Instruction
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 5.1
     \State\hspace{\algorithmicindent} Instruction 5.2
\State Instruction 6
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a huge help!